# Past Continuous and past perfect continuous for native English speakers

Tags: perfect-constructions, past-continuous

According to Martin Hewing's Advanced English Grammar:

The difference between past continuous and past perfect continuous is as follows:

> When we met Simon and Pat, **they had been riding.(=we met after they had finished)**
>
> When we met Simon and Pat, **they were riding.(=we met while they were riding)**

If we keep in mind this difference, will native speakers consider sentences like:"Jane had been suffering from flu when she was interviewed," to mean that Jane had recovered before the interview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion she was still suffering at the time of the interview, or it was obvious she had very recently had the flu and her voice was still affected for example.